# finding -k value of decrypted file (openssl)

Tags: linux, bash, encryption

Replaced old code with correct one.

The main problem turned out to be that the file type was of ISO-8859 and not "ASCII" or "ansi" probably due to the file being generated on a windows computer. It was also encrypted with an older version of openssl. The newer version uses SHA-256 while the old one uses MD5 if I'm not mistaken.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0000..9999}
do
    if openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -md md5 -in encrypted.dta -out decrypted.txt -k $i 2>/dev/null && file decrypted.txt |grep ': ISO-8859'
    then
    echo $i:; cat decrypted.txt;break
    fi
done
```

Comment: You decrypt some data with a random key but don't check whether it is correct.  openssl will succeed either way.

Comment: manually run 2x different `openssl` commands ... one that fails / one that succeeds; what do you get as a return code (`$?`) for both cases? what do you get for output (stdout, stderr) for both cases?  now (re)code to take into consideration what you find (`$?`, stderr/stdout contents)

Comment: @stark: _most_ of the time `openssl enc -d` for a padded cipher will detect wrong key but not always; see previous Q https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87518/how-to-bruteforce-4-digit-pin-with-openssl-and-open-file-in-plaintext which was effectively redirected here. But this isn't a good way to check the results.

Comment: It prints out `*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt` I've also tried filtering after whether it prints `bad decrypt`

Comment: I'm not familiar with bash, but are you sure that 0000 is not normalized to 0? Perhaps you need to make sure that `$i` is always 4 characters long and if not add leading zeros.

Comment: I've echoed i to check if there are 4 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relatively few (slightly more than 1/256) cases where `openssl enc -d` of a padded cipher does not give an error for a wrong password, it will produce essentially garbage output, but that will be the correct length or nearly so. **IF** the plaintext was ASCII (no chars with eighth bit set) there is very low probability a non-correct output will do the same, and that's easy to check:

```
for i in {0000..9999}; do 
  if openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in 65891080.enc -out 65891080.tmp 2>/dev/null -k $i && 
    file 65891080.tmp | grep -q ': ASCII text'
  then echo $i:; cat 65891080.tmp; fi
done
6543:
This is the secret text
```

Comment: This looks more like it, but it doesn't give me any output. I'm running Kali Linux and the file is .sh